# "Орёл" наконец пошел... или Запятые при однородных деепричастиях

Tags: запятые, деепричастный-оборот

"Орёл" наконец пошел, развив скорость(,) и(,) догнав эскадру, занял свое место в строю боевых кораблей.

По правилу, вроде запятые в скобках не должны ставиться, т. к. однородные деепричастные обороты.

Но в тексте произведения они поставлены, почему?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ...Если два однородных (то есть относящихся к одному и тому же
>   глаголу) одиночных деепричастия соединены союзом «и» (а также «либо»,
>   «или» и пр.), то вокруг данного союза запятые не ставятся — по
>   аналогии с однородными членами предложения.

Наши деепричастия относятся к разным глаголам: *пошёл* и *занял*.

***"Орёл" наконец пошел, развив скорость, и, догнав эскадру, занял свое место в строю боевых кораблей.***